# When Using Decision Tables to Write Pseudo Code

Tags: pseudocode

I am currently a programming student and trying to implement the use of decision tables when writing pseudo code.  I believe I understand how this process works but need some clarification if possible.

Let's say I have a decision table like the following:

[Simplified Decision Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9iCz.png)

Is it good practice to write out the pseudo using the simplified table as-is?
Meaning, do I use the rules separately for each action in a IF - ELSE IF even though the actions are the same? Or would I bring the conditions together to evaluate as an OR evaluation?

**1**

```
   IF A THEN
       IF C THEN
            X
       ELSE IF B THEN
            X 
       ....
```

OR

**2**

```
   IF A THEN
       IF B OR C THEN
            X
       ....
```

I understand that just by looking at the given example the latter would be better but when I replace the variables above with the actual pseudo having "B OR C" makes the code span two lines making it look messier than the first option.

In either case my understanding is that 2 evaluations (B, C) are being made so technically in terms of processing it would be the same or negligible (?).

If that is true then do I just go with the neater(**1**) since **2** would  be 'messier' with the IF statement (B or C) spanning two lines.

I apologize if this question is too basic or not a question worth asking.  I did check questions regarding decision tables and pseudo code but did not come across this (might have missed something or maybe the question again is too basic).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have come across a couple of points that makes sense regarding pseudocode.  Does not necessarily answer my specific question regarding decision table -> pseudo code but this clarifies it much more for me.

[Write Pseudocode (wikihow)](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-Pseudocode)

From the above article there are a couple points:

- *Pseudocode serves as an informal guide, a **tool** for thinking through program problems, and a **communication device** that can help you explain your ideas to other people.*
- ***Clarity*** is a primary goal of pseudocode, and it may help if you work within accepted programming conventions. As you develop your pseudocode into actual code, you will need to transcribe it into a programming language – so it can help to structure your outline with this in mind.

I believe these two general but key points answer my own question. This may have been something obvious but I think I was too caught up in the "coding" aspect when writing the pseudo. And also my excuse of "still learning".

So, clarity and readability in mind then implementing the pseudocode which in the end is a tool.

I would appreciate it if someone would correct me if I haven't understood this correctly or if anyone had different thoughts.